# Got response code '400' contacting Elasticsearch at URL in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am new to elasticsearch. I tried to configure elastisearch, Kibana , logstash with MQTT plugin. I supposed to send logs to elasticseach through logstash MQTT plugin. I installed them on Mac locally, but when starting logstash, it throws following error.

```
[2021-11-12T17:26:37,976][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][logstash_pipeline] Unable to get license information {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :message=>"Got response code '400' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://localhost:9200/_license'"}
```

my logstash configuration file islike:

```
input {
  mqtt {
    host => "localhost"
    port => 1883
    topic => "test"
    qos => 0
    certificate_path => "/Users/john/logstash-7.10.2/logstash/m2mqtt_ca.crt"
    
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    #user => "elastic"
    #password => "changeme"
  }
}
```

can anybody tell, what was the issue?

Comment: Which version of ES did you install?

Comment: I installed elasticsearch-7.10.2
logstash-7.10.2
Kibana - 7.10.2

Comment: Just to make sure, are you sure it's elasticsearch and not opensearch?

Comment: yes, confirmed. it is elasticsearch.